# Allow user to submit comment based on (2) tables?

Tags: php, mysql

ERROR on this Php file:

```
    <?php // Insert Comments into Database that user provides
        //Get values of fields entered
        $comment = $_POST['addComment'];
        $pID4 = filter_var( $_POST['pID'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
        $cID = $_POST['prefix'] . $_POST['code'];
    require_once('inc/dbc1.php');
    $pdo4 = new PDO('mysql:host=###;dbname=####', $username, $password);
    $pdo4->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
 /* Error on this line --> */   $sth4 = $pdo4->prepare('INSERT INTO Comment (info, pID, cID) VALUES('$comment',?,?);');
    $sth4->execute(array($comment, $pID4, $cID));  
    ?>
```

**ERROR:**  syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, the `info` field is required (i.e. cannot be null) but I can't see where you are setting the $info variable to pass into the prepared statement.

Try restarting mysql in debug mode, which should allow you to get the exact query being run - you can then see if it's a MySQL problem or a PHP problem.

Comment: Thats the problem: `info` isn't passed, so `NULL` is used, but it's not allowed to be `NULL` -> error. Solution: always include `info` in the INSERT query, or give `info` a default value in the db.

Comment: How isnt info being passed? In the php, I have `comment = $_POST['addComment'];` and in the sth : `$sth4 = $pdo4->prepare('INSERT INTO Comment (info, pID, cID) VALUES(?,?,?);'); ` 

In Essence: info field is being pulled the the $_POST since the name/value of the field is "addComment" in the html.  Does that make it more clear

Comment: @user700070 Yes, sorry you're right - I can see it now. So first check that `$comment` has a value - just do something like die($comment) after you've set it. Then see what query is actually being run with `die($sth4->query());`

Comment: Couldn't I just easily echo $sth4?

Comment: If you mean why `die()` instead of `echo`, it's just a quick way of seeing the error message without anything else getting in the way, but you can use your preferred method. I personally use `fwrite()` into a log file. If you mean why use the `query()` method, it's because the PDO class doesn't have a `toString()` method, so doing `echo $sth4` will tell you it's an object but nothing else. You could use `$sth4->debugDumpParams()` instead, which will tell you all the bound variables.

Comment: Please see updated code, I passed $comment into it, but now I get a new error, see bolded above please.

Comment: @user700070 This `$sth4 = $pdo4->prepare('INSERT INTO Comment (info, pID, cID) VALUES('$comment',?,?);');` should be replaced with `$sth4 = $pdo4->prepare('INSERT INTO Comment (info, pID, cID) VALUES('.$comment.',?,?);');`. (i.e. dots around the `$comment` variable)

Comment: This gives me an error of: `Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens' on line 65`  . I also updated this code above to show you exactly whats there.

Comment: @user700070 Oops, sorry I wasn't reading properly before. Try replacing `'.$comment.'` (including quotes) with just `?` (no quotes).

Comment: This gives the error of : `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in`  ---- thoughts?

Comment: @user700070 Check your brackets match - looks like you have one too many.

Comment: Blowski - please look at updated php which is giving error, what is the problem here?  If I just put a `?` in for `$comment` , it gives me the NULL error.

Comment: @user700070 ...which sounds like you have nothing in the $comment variable. You need to work out what's in `$comment` and if that's empty, check what's in `$_POST['addComment']`.

Comment: Could I use something like `if(empty($_POST['addComment'])){echo "empty";} else {echo "full"; }`    ?

Comment: @user700070 Yes, that will tell you whether `$_POST['addComment']` has a value. (That's a situation where I prefer to write `die($_POST['addComment'])` because it's easier to see, but your way works too.)

Comment: Can you help me on where I should put : die($_POST['addComment']) ?

Comment: @user700070 As it's in the $_POST array, if it has a value it will have a value anywhere. However, by putting it right at the beginning of the script, you can see quickly what it's value is.

Answer (score 0):

You're not outputting your pID into your form, because of mal-formed string output:

```
echo "<option>".$row3['prefix']." ".$row3['code']."</option>"; }
echo "</select>
<input type='text' id='addComment' name='addComment' tabindex='3' value='Enter comment' />
<input type='hidden' name='pID' value='<?php echo $pID4; ?>'>
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ here
</form>";
```

At the point I've indicated, you're still within the double-quoted string for the 'echo' command, so that PHP never gets executed, as it's within the string. What you'll end up with is an HTML tag that looks like

```
...<input type="hidden' name='pID' value='<?php echo 1234;?>'>...
```

in the browser, which is not what you want.

You really need to either "break out" of PHP mode, or use HEREDOCs. Either will let you output multi-line text chunks without having to jump through hoops with mixing quoting styles, and also let any decent syntax-highlighting editor catch errors such as this.

Comment: Can you please show some proper code example of all this? It would be much appreciated Marc.

Comment: to break out, just go `?>` and you're back into plain html. Heredocs are document on the php site: http://php.net/heredoc

Comment: I understand the delimiters of php, im lost why this isnt grabbing the inputted 'comment' value. Why is it null??? Is something wrong with my variable?

Comment: try doing a `var_dump($_POST)` and see what IS being submitted. There may be a typo elsewhere in your html that's breaking the form, such as a misplaced `"`

Answer (score 0):

```
$pdo4->prepare('INSERT INTO Comment (info, pID, cID) VALUES('.$comment.',?,?);');
```

that's wrong. use this:

```
 $pdo4->prepare('INSERT INTO Comment (info, pID, cID) VALUES(?,?,?);');
```

Comment: That gives error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object

Comment: I have searched a bit for this error. it seems to be a php bug. Upgrade your php version